Querying if subset of points are all within given distance of single point
I’m just getting started with PostGIS and have converted a table to have geographic points instead of discrete lat/lon fields. I now need to write a query to determine whether a set of rows that have unprocessed = true, box_id = n, created_at > x ever have points that move further than n meters from the point of the first row.
I presume I need to use the ST_Distance function, but haven’t managed to get much farther than this.  I can’t work out if I need a self-join, and if so what to join on.

So I’ve now managed to come up with the below, but would still be interested if anyone else has other/better solutions.
SELECT data_raw_samples.id, other_samples.id, ST_Distance(data_raw_samples.point, other_samples.point)
FROM data_raw_samples
LEFT JOIN data_raw_samples AS other_samples
  ON other_samples.box_id = data_raw_samples.box_id
WHERE data_raw_samples.id = #{initial_sample.id}
  AND other_samples.processed = false
  AND other_samples.val = 'A'
  AND ST_Distance(data_raw_samples.point, other_samples.point) > #{minimum_distance_moved}


If you are only interested in the points that have moved, you don't need the left join.  An inner join will return only the rows that have a distance greater than n.  You may as well also filter the initial record out of the other_samples because that distance will always be 0.
with initial_sample as (
    SELECT * FROM data_raw_samples where id = #{initial_sample.id}
)
select a.id initial_id, b.id other_id, st_distance(a.point,b.point) dist
from initial_sample a
inner join data_raw_samples b 
on a.id != b.id and a.box_id = b.box_id 
and st_distance(a.point,b.point) > #{minimum_distance_moved}
where b.val = 'A' and b.processed = false;

You also mention created_at > x.  If you want to add that, you could do this:
with initial_sample as (
    SELECT * FROM data_raw_samples where id = #{initial_sample.id}
),
other_samples as (
    select * from data_raw_samples where id != #{initial_sample.id} 
    and not processed and val = 'A' and created_at::timestamptz > (#{x})::timestamptz
)
select a.id initial_id, b.id other_id, st_distance(a.point,b.point) dist 
from initial_sample a
inner join other_samples b
on a.box_id = b.box_id and st_distance(a.point,b.point) > #{minimum_distance_moved}

